# SIGCHLD sended by another process to parent

Tags: signals, fork, parent-child, kill, sigchld

Let's assume that our process creates a child and then calls `wait()`.

When I try to send signal() or do

```
kill -SIGCHLD <PID>
```

nothing happens at all.

So the question is: How does the process in Linux determine that signal `SIGCHLD` hadn't been sent by the child? Or, maybe, there is some another mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel takes care of this.

`wait()` is **not** a signal handler listening for (any) `SIGCHLD` sent to a process, as it might be established via `sigaction()` or `signal()`.

From [`wait()`'s POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) (emphasis by me):

> The  wait()  and  waitpid()  functions  shall  obtain status information pertaining ***to one of the caller's child processes***.